# No route matches [GET] "/companies/9" Rails.root: C:/Users/Anuradha-PC/Desktop/Ruby/Jobs_board2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i was try to create company it will show error:

> No route matches [GET] "/companies/9" Rails.root:
>   C:/Users/Anuradha-PC/Desktop/Ruby/Jobs_board2

In my CompanyController I have:

```
def show
  if @company = Company.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
    @company_user_id = current_user.id
  else
    redirect_to new_company_path
  end

  def create            
    @company = current_user.companies.build(company_params)
    if @company.save
      flash[:success]= "success"
      redirect_to @company
    else
      flash[:error]=@company.errors.full_messages
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:c_name,:c_description)
  end
```

In the models:

```
    class Company < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to:user
      has_many:jobs
    end

    class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
      has_many :companies
      has_many :jobs
    end
```

Routes:

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :users
      resources :jobs
      resources :companies, except: :show do
        get :show, on: :collection, as: :show
      end
      # resources :users do
      #   resources :companies
      # end
      root 'jobs#index'
    end
```

When i was try to create company it will show the error.

Comment: because there is no `action` or `function` available in your `controller` called `def show`. add it, will resolve your issue. NOTE: make sure about `routes`

Comment: i forgot to add the def show  to this question, still have a error

Comment: You have no `show` action for a particular company but only for a collection of company.

Comment: Thanks a Lot , it's working fine

Comment: Not sure if it's the case in your actual code, but you're missing an `end` on the `show` view / before `create`....